# Jupyter Notebook Dockerfile with Volumes Not Updating Files(fails to save)

Tags: python, bash, docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

**Problem:**

I have created a Dockerfile for a Jupyter Notebook with volumes to enable persistent storage. However, after building and running the Docker container, I noticed that the Jupyter Notebook does not update the `.ipynb` or any other files present in the `notebooks` folder. I cannot update the files both on the Docker machine and on the host machine. Below are the Dockerfile and the bash script I am using:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM jupyter/base-notebook:python-3.11

# Install the dependencies from the requirements.txt file
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Expose Jupyter Notebook port
EXPOSE 8888

# Copy the notebooks directory to the container's /app directory
COPY notebooks /app/notebooks

# Run Jupyter Notebook on container startup
CMD ["jupyter", "notebook", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--port=8888", "--no-browser", "--allow-root"]
```

**Bash Script (`run_docker.sh`):**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Build the Docker image using the Dockerfile in the current directory
docker build -t my_jupyter_image .

# Create a Docker volume for the ipynb files in the current directory
docker volume create --name notebook_volume --opt type=none --opt device="$(pwd)/notebooks" --opt o=bind

# Run the Docker container with the Jupyter Notebook image and disable login
docker run -d -p 8888:8888 \
           --name my_jupyter_container \
           -v notebook_volume:/app/notebooks \
           my_jupyter_image \
           start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.token=''
```

**Additional Context:**

After launching the Docker container, I can access the Jupyter Notebook at `http://localhost:8888`. However, when I create or modify any files inside the `notebooks` folder on my local machine, the changes are not reflected within the Jupyter Notebook running in the container. The container seems to be using a snapshot of the `notebooks` folder from when it was initially created.

**Desired Outcome:**

I would like the Jupyter Notebook to automatically update and synchronize changes made to files inside the `notebooks` folder on my local machine with the files within the Docker container. How can I achieve this behavior while still retaining the flexibility of using password-based authentication?